# Count occurrences of assorted items in a List in a Dictionary Value in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

The following reads a text file that contains entries such as:

```
Emma Woodhouse,Package
Emma Woodhouse,Letter
Emma Woodhouse,Letter
```

I've taken the text, converted it to a list to split it around the comma, then created a Dictionary to hold each person as the key and each item delivered to them as a value. So the code below would produce:

```
{'Emma Woodhouse': ['Letter', 'Letter', 'Package']}
```

My problem is counting the occurances of each type of item, so when a user interrogates the dictionary with 'Emma Woodhouse', I want it to print:

```
2 Letters
1 Package
```

Before I even get to the issue of pluralising entries greater than 1 (!), I'm struggling to get the information to print as desired. Any help would be appreciated!

```
mail_list = []

for entry in open ('mail.txt'):
  listed = entry.strip().split(',')
  mail_list.append(listed) 

import collections

mail_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for person, package in mail_list:
  mail_dict[person].append(package)

name = input('Name: ')

for name in mail_dict:
  for item in mail_dict.values():
    count = 0
    for individual in item: 
      count += 1
    print(count, individual)
```

I know the above is probably very 'ugly' - please bear with me! It's printing far too many lines and the wrong totals : /

Comment: You've reused 'name' `for name ...` did you mean `if name in...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the list method `count`:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4,]

a.count(1) == 3
a.count(2) == 2
a.count(3) == 3
a.count(4) == 3
```

You also need to use the `name` from `input('Name: ')` to access the dictionary, rather than iterating through it:

```
name = input('Name: ')

for item_list in mail_dict[name]:
    # count items
```

Comment: Oooh. Like. Do I even need a dictionary then or would your run this on it?

Comment: Yes, a dictionary would be good, you need one to pair the names to the items.

Comment: Thanks! Getting there now. It's returning the correct values, but randomising who it returns them for - assuming because Dicts are unsorted. Getting there though! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `Counter` from `collections` module.

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: mail_dict = {'Emma Woodhouse': ['Letter', 'Letter', 'Package']}

In [3]: [Counter(mail_dict[key]) for key in mail_dict]
Out[3]: [Counter({'Letter': 2, 'Package': 1})]
```

Comment: Thanks - this is getting me even closer.

Comment: Agreed about using the collections module. It should be better known.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, try it out

```
import collections
def parse(mail_dict):
         return {i:dict(collections.Counter(mail_dict[i])) for i in mail_dict.keys()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my approach:

```
import sys
file = open(sys.argv[-1], "r").read()
wordictionary={}
for word in file.split():
    if word not in wordictionary:
        wordictionary[word] = 1
    else:
        wordictionary[word] += 1
sortable = [(wordictionary[key], key) for key in wordictionary]
sortable.sort()
sortable.reverse()
for member in sortable: print (member)
```